# Setting Wix shortcut with environment variable workingdirectory

Tags: wix, wix3.6

I'm trying to create a shortcut in WIX with teh following WorkingDirectory:

```
<Shortcut Id="PowerShellShortcut" Name="$(var.PRODUCTNAME) Powershell Prompt" Description="$(var.PRODUCTNAME) Powershell Prompt" WorkingDirectory="%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%" Target="[POWERSHELLEXE]" Arguments='-noexit -command "Import-Module [APPLICATIONFOLDER]Binaries\MA.dll | Out-Null"' />
```

When I try to build I get the following error:

> Error 1   The Shortcut/@WorkingDirectory attribute's value, '%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%', is not a legal identifier.  Identifiers may contain ASCII characters A-Z, a-z, digits, underscores (_), or periods (.).  Every identifier must begin with either a letter or an underscore.

Is there a workaround to set the literal string "%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%" as the WorkingDirectory of a Shortcut?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876834/setting-working-directory-for-a-wix-shortcut

Answer (score 2):

Per the documentation on the [Shortcut Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371847.aspx), the working directory (WkDir) stores the name of a property that has the value you want stored into the shortcut. This property may be a DirProperty (i.e. also a reference into the Directory Table), or it may just hold a hardcoded string itself. If you want the final shortcut to have the literal text `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%`, then set your working directory to something like `WKDIR_HOME` which is the name of a property you have set to `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't fool WiX, so we're back to square one.

Comment: Then we would have two identical questions. I did as you described but WiX converted the property to a string literal and gave the same error about not allowing the `%` character.

Comment: Sorry, I was using a preprocessor variable, not a property. So I added a property `<Property Id="WKDIR_HOME" Value="%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%" />` and added it to my shortcut like this: `WorkingDirectory="WKDIR_HOME"` and now the shortcut's "Start in:" it shows "H:\" which is the value of %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%, instead of the literal text `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%`. I guess that's good enough for now.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use environment variables like `%HOMEDRIVE%` in `.wxs` files. Instead of `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%`, try using `$(env.HOMEDRIVE)$(env.HOMEPATH)`

Comment: It doesn't like that because my %HOMEDRIVE% is "H:\". WiX says, "`Identifiers may contain ASCII characters A-Z, a-z, digits, underscores (_), or periods (.).`"